# Extract text from pdf, MS ofiices file and other document

Tags: 12.04, command-line, software-recommendation

I need a command line tool that will extract plain text from MS office files(all formats), pdf and other file formats.

I looked at libre office command line but was not able to find the filters for all formats

Comment: I got pdftotext and for .doc I have got unoconv but for docx,pptx,xls,xlsx I have not found any.

Comment: For .doc, there's also antiword. The pdftotext that coder mentioned is part of poppler.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question (e. g. for each distinct file format family), so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

For office files you can use:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir out‐put_dir] file
```

More about:

- See `man libreoffice`
- [How to extract just plain text from .doc & .docx files? (unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files-unix)

For pdf files, I see that you have found `pdftotext`.